# Unknown web method xxxxx on ALL webmethods

Tags: c#, ajax, webmethod

I have a solution where I have a couple of [WebMethod] on various aspx-pages.
They have all worked fine but after getting back from vacations I get the "unknown web method" on ALL calls to the webmethods on all pages I use them.

I have no compilation errors, all pages work just fine with their postback functionality but as I said, where ever I use jquery/ajax I now get this error.
I tried clean solution but with no luck..

This is all locally on my computer. The corresponding test/production environments work just fine.

What could have caused this to happen?

This is just one example of a method that stopped working:

```
[WebMethod]
public static bool SaveAdvice(string countryCode, ...)
{
  // Some code
  return true
}
```

Comment: So the web methods are still `public static`?

Comment: Yes, they are all public static with the webmethod attribute which has been working for at least a year. But here I come back after summer vacations and none of them work..

Comment: Additional information is that if I compile and copy the the testserver the errors are transferred to the testserver. For a while I though it was locally only where the problem occured but it follows my compiled code.